# Obtain control value within DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like you to help me, as I can extract the value of a control that is inside RowDetailsTemplate, my code xaml is the following (it is possible to say that the datagrid is linked with itemssource):

```
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
  <TextBox Name="txtNombre" Text="{Binding nombre}"/>
</DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

Now the question is: How to extract the value of txtName by clicking on a button?

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  // ¿?
}
```

Thank you very much for the help.
Greetings.

Edit 1:

The control DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid Name="datagrid">
  <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <TextBox Name="txtNombre" Text="{Binding nombre}"/>
  </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

The control Button:

```
<Button Name="btnSave" Click="btnSave_Click" 
DataContext="{Binding ElementName=datagrid, Path=RowDetailsTemplate}">Click me</Button>
```

And now? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simple WPF, using an MVVM approach, use an ICommand as your button command, then as a commandParameter, use the value of the textBox, in your case if it is something simple, use the

> {Binding nombre}

as your binding.

If the button is in another control, you can use ElementName, RelativeResource, Ancestor, etc to get its reference, check out the [WPF Cheetsheet](http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/WpfBinding.pdf) on how to bind to any element in your userControl.

Comment: Sorry, forget to mention that the button is not inside the datagrid control, the button is inside a ToolBar control.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check how to reference the control you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, could you continue to guide me please? Can you check the original post edition?

Comment: Does your DataGrid only contain one element? Does the DataGrid also contain the button?

Comment: It does not contain only that control, in fact I have many more controls.